# How to require third-party js package when developing Jupyter Notebook extension

Tags: jupyter-notebook, mermaid

I want to write an extension of Jupyter Notebook extension for [mermaid](https://mermaidjs.github.io). Or more common, how to webpack an npm package to Jupyter Notebook Extension.

But when I include the `mermaid` package in main.js, encounter the following error:

```
utils.js:62 Failed to load extension: ["nbextensions/notebook_mermaid/mermaid"] TypeError: _.constant is not a function
    at Object../node_modules/graphlibrary/lib/alg/dijkstra.js (mermaid.js:26950)
    at __webpack_require__ (mermaid.js:30)
    at Object../node_modules/graphlibrary/lib/alg/index.js (mermaid.js:27094)
    at __webpack_require__ (mermaid.js:30)
    at Object../node_modules/graphlibrary/index.js (mermaid.js:26820)
    at __webpack_require__ (mermaid.js:30)
    at Object../src/diagrams/flowchart/flowRenderer.js (mermaid.js:64777)
    at __webpack_require__ (mermaid.js:30)
    at Object../src/mermaidAPI.js (mermaid.js:71197)
    at __webpack_require__ (mermaid.js:30)
```

I have uploaded the code to github,
https://github.com/Honghe/notebook_mermaid